# How to sort drush status messages in test scripts?

Tags: testing, drush

I'm using drush to run test scripts agains my drupal 7 installation. Simply calling:

```
$ drush scr path/to/myScript.php
```

My script is using `drupal_set_message()` to output status of my test scripts.

My problem is the output is sorted by importance, like that:

```
Test 1339 failed.                [error]
Test 1338 failed.                [error]
Something strange happened!      [warning]
Test 1337 successful.            [status]
Script starting.                 [notice]
Script finished after 1234ms.    [notice]
```

Is there any way to sort the output of the messages by the time they get called in my script, it would look much more logical like that:

```
Script starting.                 [notice]
Test 1337 successful.            [status]
Test 1338 failed.                [error]
Something strange happened!      [warning]
Test 1339 failed.                [error]
Script finished after 1234ms.    [notice]
```

Is that possible somehow? Is `drupal_set_message()` the wrong approach? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log your debugging messages in database using [watchdog](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7)
 and you will find the logged message in order at "admin/reports/dtblog"

**Updated:**
Check the document page, as for [status] , watchdog has $severity parameter to set the status for your message.Following values can be set as status for the logged message.

```
WATCHDOG_EMERGENCY: Emergency, system is unusable.
WATCHDOG_ALERT: Alert, action must be taken immediately.
WATCHDOG_CRITICAL: Critical conditions.
WATCHDOG_ERROR: Error conditions.
WATCHDOG_WARNING: Warning conditions.
WATCHDOG_NOTICE: (default) Normal but significant conditions.
WATCHDOG_INFO: Informational messages.
WATCHDOG_DEBUG: Debug-level messages.
```

As a simple example, check this

```
 watchdog('your_script_name', '!message', array('!message' => "something_happened"), WATCHDOG_ERROR);
```

the above will log message when called keeping severity as "error".

Comment: Good alternative, indeed, but there is no `[status]`, isn't it? Debug, Info and Notice are only displayed in verbose mode.

Comment: please check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the severity levels. `[debug]` is only shown with `--debug` and both `[info]` & `[notice]` are shown with `--verbose` options set. I'm looking for the normal green drupal `[status]` without passing any verbose or debug options but that seems not to exist in `watchdog()` due to some strange RCF declarations. But thanks anyways for your reply, I think I can live with that.